# Identify potentiometer [Radio repair]

Tags: identification, potentiometer

I need a replacement part for the potentiometer depicted below, dimensions are approx. 16x13.5 mm.
The bottom reads "B100K" and "SEL" and the resistance between the two outermost contacts is a little less than 100k, but a quick Google search didn't come up with a definite match (this particular model has a small inside thread to connect to the radio dial). The radio was built around 2012, if it helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a 100K linear taper pot, but that knob connection is typical of a variable capacitor rather than a pot. What country was it made in?

Comment: what is wrong with that one? ... it looks like it can be taken apart for cleaning

Comment: ^^^  That  -- Pop the top cover off, clean everything with compressed air and 100% isopropyl alcohol (if you can find it!), and my favorite trick - Bend the wiper ever so slightly, such that it rides on virgin material.  It'll work like brand new

Comment: @Spehro: I don't know where it was manufactured, but I was surprised as well to *not* find a variable capacitor (this is the knob for FM/AM tuning, so...).

Comment: Yes, it's a pot specifically designed for radio tuning applications. Probably made by one of the many manufacturers in China.

Comment: @jsotola: I am hesitant to dismantle it if I don't know whether there is a replacement in case I mess up  :)

Comment: ok, don't take it apart ... wash it with isopropyl ... then spray some light silicone spray into it

Comment: SEL was a [German company.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._Lorenz_AG)  Standard Electrik Lorenz.  The last company to carry the SEL name and logo went out of business in 2006.  Maybe your gadget was built from old stocks of an SEL part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 100K linear taper pot designed with a mechanical construction to allow use of hardware and knob for radio tuning. Probably made by one of the many potentiometer manufacturers in China. Here is a [similar](http://www.soundwell-cn.com/m/products/detail/266) construction one:

[image]

I don't think you're going to be able to easily find a replacement unless you live in China (and even there it would not be straightforward).

As @jsotola and Kyle suggest, you can probably fix whatever is wrong with that one by carefully opening it and possibly adding some conductive ink to the ends, and cleaning the element/wiper with appropriate products. Typically the wiper has only a thin plating layer, and the element also is fragile, so be careful not to permanently damage the pot.